# trying to log in and scrape a website through asp.net

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have wrote a program with the aim of logging into one of my companies websites and then scraping data with aim of making data collection quicker. this is using requests and beautiful soup.

I can get it to print out the html code for a page but I cant get it to log in past the aspx and then print the html on the page after.

below is the code im using and my headers and params. any help would be appreciated

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL="http://mycompanywebsiteloginpage.co.uk/Login.aspx"
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0 Iceweasel/44.0.2"}

username="myusername"
password="mypassword"

s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r=s.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

VIEWSTATE=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
EVENTTARGET=soup.find(id="__EVENTTARGET")['value']
EVENTARGUEMENT=soup.find(id="__EVENTARGUMENT")['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbEngineerUsername":username,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbEngineerPassword":password,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbSiteOwnerEmail":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbSiteOwnerPassword":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbAdminName":username,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbAdminPassword":password,
"__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION,
"__EVENTTARGET":EVENTTARGET,
"--EVENTARGUEMENT":EVENTARGUEMENT}

r = s.post(URL, data=login_data)
r = requests.get("http://mycompanywebsitespageafterthelogin.co.uk/Secure/")
print (r.url)
print (r.text)
```

FROM DATA

```html
__VIEWSTATE:"DAwNEAIAAA4BBQAOAQ0QAgAADgEFAw4BDRACDwEBBm9ubG9hZAFkU2hvd1BhbmVsKCdjdGwwMF9Db250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxX19wbkFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3JzJywgZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ2FkbWluTG9naW5MaW5rJykpOwAOAQUBDgENEAIAAA4DBQEFBwULDgMNEAIMDwEBDUFsdGVybmF0ZVRleHQBDldEU0kgRGFzaGJvYXJkAAAAAA0QAgAADgIFAAUBDgINEAIPAQEEVGV4dAEEV0RTSQAAAA0QAgwPAQEHVmlzaWJsZQgAAAAADRACDwECBAABBFdEU2kAAAAAAABCX8QugS7ztoUJMfDmZ0s20ZNQfQ=="
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbEngineerUsername:"myusername"
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbEngineerPassword:"mypassword"
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbSiteOwnerEmail:""
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_tbSiteOwnerPassword:""
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbAdminName:"myusername"
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbAdminPassword:"mypassword"
__EVENTVALIDATION:"HQABAAAA/////wEAAAAAAAAADwEAAAAKAAAACBzHEFXh+HCtf3vdl8crWr6QZnmaeK7pMzThEoU2hwqJxnlkQDX2XLkLAOuKEnW/qBMtNK2cdpQgNxoGtq65"
__EVENTTARGET:"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_btAdminLogin"
__EVENTARGUMENT:""
```

REQUEST COOKIES

```html
ASP.NET_SessionId:"11513CDDE31AF267CCD87BAB"
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```html
Cache-Control:"private"
Connection:"Keep-Alive"
Content-Length:"123"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
Date:"Thu, 28 Jul 2016 13:37:45 GMT"
Keep-Alive:"timeout=15, max=91"
Location:"/Secure/"
Server:"Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)"
x-aspnet-version:"2.0.50727"
```

REQUEST HEADERS

```html
Host:"mycompanywebsite.co.uk"
User-Agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0 Iceweasel/44.0.2"
Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language:"en-US,en;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding:"gzip, deflate"
Referer:"http://mycompanywebsiteloginpage/Login.aspx"
Cookie:"ASP.NET_SessionId=F11CB47B137ADB66D2274758"
Connection:"keep-alive"
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for one question. Could you specify what part does not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line

```
r = requests.get("http://mycompanywebsitespageafterthelogin.co.uk/Secure/")
```

to use your session object

```
r = s.get("http://mycompanywebsitespageafterthelogin.co.uk/Secure/")
```